# ClistView Yii positionning

Tags: php, yii, clistview

I wanted to simplify my views and take advantage of the ClisView features (sorting, paging,...).

(I had foreach to loop on the comments lists and display the list).

To achieve this,  I renderPartial my _comments view

```
$this->renderPartial('_comments',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
```

and in my _comments view,  in order to list the comments related to a post,  I use

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'itemView'=>'_comment',
    'template'=>"{items}\n{pager}",
)); ?>
```

the _comment view simply contains the following code

```
<div class="comment">


    <div class="content">
        <?php
            $this->beginWidget('CMarkdown', array('purifyOutput'=>true));
            echo $data->content;
            $this->endWidget();
        ?>
    </div>

</div>
```

it works fine,  it displays the correct data  but not in the right place.

To be clear,  let say I have 2 posts , POST 1 has 3 comments and POST 2  has 2 comments.

### If I click on the POST 1 link to comments,  it looks correct, it displays

Post 1  - link to comments

Comment 1 (of post 1)

Comment 2 (of post 1)

Comment 3 (of post 1)

Post 2- link to comments

---

### but if I click on the POST 2  link to comments, it displays the following

Post 1 - link to comments

Comment 1 (of post 2)

Comment 2 (of post 2)

Post 2 - link to comments

---

So the comments are displayed under post 1 and not post 2.

### I logically expected

Post 1 - link to comments

Post 2 - link to comments

Comment 1 (of post 2)

Comment 2 (of post 2)

---

I must clarify that the list of posts  is also displayed by a cListView  and when I look to the source code the class names generated are identicals.

here is the code where the dataprovider is defined

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria(array(
            'condition'=>'post_id='.$post_id,
            'order'=>'create_time DESC',

            ));
            $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Comment', array(
            'pagination'=>array(
            'pageSize'=>Yii::app()->params['commentsPerPage'],
            ),
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
            ));
            $this->renderPartial('_comments',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        ));
```

So my question would be,  how to ask ClistView to generate different class names ?

Do you know how I can correclty display the comments ?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Where does the value of $dataProvider come from in your controller?

Comment: it comes from the action View of my controller which call the renderPartial _comments  view   @jbg

Comment: Sorry I mean, can you show us where it comes from? The code where you define $dataProvider = ...

Comment: I updated the post with the code.  I added also that the list of posts is also displayed by a cListView and when I look to the source code the class names generated are identicals. So it is normal that the ClistVIew go to the first class.  And my question is now, how to make ClistView generated a different class by record ?  @jbg